# Ant Script to Automate the build process

Tags: ant, build, build-automation, antbuilder

I Want to automate the ANT build process for deploying the applicaiton.

I want to write a ANT script which will recurringly should look for the 
  build.xml files in the folder and run them, if the sub build is failed 
  it should skip and continue to other script by writing log.
Could any please post the idea which can help or a sample.

```
RootFolder
    |
    |-----Folder1
    |            |
    |            |--SubFolder1
    |            |            build.xml
    |            |--SubFolder2
    |            |            build.xml
    |-----Folder2
    |           build.xml
    |
    |-----Folder3
             build.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, thank you all for the reply, I used below technique to handle the situation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="MasterBuildPrj" default="MasterBuild">
    <macrodef name="iterate">
        <attribute name="target"/>
        <sequential>
            <subant target="@{target}">
                <fileset dir="." 
                         includes="**/build.xml"
                         excludes="build.xml"/>
            </subant>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
    <target name="MasterBuild"  description="Build all sub projects">
        <iterate target="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean"  description="Clean all sub projects">
        <iterate target="clean"/>
    </target>   
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task

```
<project name="Subant demo" default="deploy-everything">
    <target name="deploy-everything">
        <subant>
            <fileset dir="." includes="**/build.xml" excludes="build.xml"/>
            <target name="clean"/>
            <target name="deploy"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
</project>
```

This will find all "build.xml" files and call the "clean deploy" targets on each.

While it's neat to automatically pick up the sub folder builds, it rarely works in large projects unless the builds are independent of each other (build order is important).

The following example uses an explicit filelist, instead of a fileset which is unordered:

```
<project name="Subant demo" default="deploy-everything">
    <target name="deploy-everything">
        <subant>
            <filelist dir=".">
                <file name="Folder1/SubFolder1/build.xml"/>
                <file name="Folder1/SubFolder2/build.xml"/>
                ..
            </filelist>
            <target name="clean"/>
            <target name="build"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
</project>
```

Finally, the most advanced solution is to use a dependency manager like [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to declare each module's dependencies in an "ivy.xml" file. Setup properly, this makes each sub module build more stand-alone. To solve the build "everything in only go problem" ivy provides a [buildlist](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html) task that can automatically determine the correct build order:

```
<target name="deploy-everything">
    <ivy:buildlist reference="build-path">
        <fileset dir="." includes="**/build.xml" excludes="build.xml"/>
    </ivy:buildlist>

    <subant buildpathref="build-path">
        <target name="clean"/>
        <target name="build"/>
    </subant>
</target>
```

Comment: True , it really works in big projects , build order is also important, can you look at my solution is there any chance to provide priority out there...:)

Comment: @Azhar Using ivy's buildlist task to the only way I know to automatically determine the build order. It does this based on intermodule depedencies created in the ivy.xml files.