# Ant resourcecount , how can I count the number of commas delimited existing in property

Tags: ant, properties, count

My xml does not work:

When I run in command line
ant compile -Dmodules=a,b,c

My build file need to count how many modules in modules parameters, compile them one by one using for loop

```
<target name="count_modules">
    <resourcecount property="count">
        <tokens>
            <concat>
                <filterchain>
                    <tokenfilter>
                        <stringtokenizer delims=","/>
                    </tokenfilter>
                </filterchain>
                <propertyresource name="modules" />
            </concat>
        </tokens>
    </resourcecount>
    <echo message="count is ${count}" />
</target>
```

count will always return 1
  [echo] count is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [propertyresource](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#propertyresource) will return a single resource to the [concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task which is designed to act on resources like files.

This complex piece of logic is best replaced by an in-line [script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html).

```
<project name="myproject" default="count_modules">

    <property name="modules" value="a,b,c"/>

    <target name="count_modules">
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            modules = project.getProperty("modules");
            project.setProperty("count", modules.split(",").length);
        ]]></script>

        <echo message="Number of modules: ${count}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### Running sub-module builds

The [for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) is not part of core ant, it's part of an extension called [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). My advice is to use the [subant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) when invoking sub-module builds. The following answer has some simple and advanced examples of its use:

- [Ant Script to Automate the build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785975/ant-script-to-automate-the-build-process/13786739#13786739)